# Nuxt and Contentful: duplicated routes

Tags: nuxt.js, contentful

I have a static website where I'm also running a blog with the content from Contentful and everything inside the blog works fine.
However, when generating the Nuxt routes, I have duplication with my posts URLs falling under /blog/post-title (which works fine and is the desired result), but also being generated with an error one level above as /post-title.

Any ideas on how to rewrite this? I've seen multiple versions of the code below.

```
generate: {
  routes() {
    return Promise.all([
      client.getEntries({
        content_type: "blogPost"
      })
    ]).then(([posts]) => {
      return [
        ...posts.items.map(posts => `blog/${posts.fields.slug}`),
      ];
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: If you feel like my answer solved your issue, please accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, contentful is probably doing the generation by itself already. Telling Nuxt to exclude it's own routes could be a nice idea. We do have exactly this property hopefully: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#exclude

You can pretty much ignore all of your routes and let Contentful manage by itself but you will probably need a middleground (and to adapt the regex).

But a naive and simple solution would be to do:

```js
export default {
  generate: {
    exclude: [
      /^\/pages/
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but you're right about the middle ground.
The thing is, I also have a number of folders under /pages and I do want them to be generated, only need to exclude the pages that are coming from Contentful.
Not sure this approach will work because the Contentful routes I want to exclude are in the same level as the pages I want to keep. Any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Could exclude just the `blog` directory.

Comment: No need for that. Inf fact, as you said, Contentful is probably adding the blog posts on the top level so I had to add the code above to create the blog directory, which is the desired place.
Not sure how could I exclude only the top-level duplicated blog posts while keeping all the pages in the same level.
Will keep looking for an answer, really appreciate you took the time.